# How do I unlock this electric burner?

Tags: stove, safety-switch

At a short term rental property. The stovetop is locked. I don’t know how to unlock it and am not even sure I can read the stylized brand name

[image]

Comment: Landlord should know, they are responsible for maintenance, or have a reason.

Comment: just in case, try a press-and-hold on the lock button, or on the power button.

Comment: It might help to narrow the brand down if you indicated where in the world you are located.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because [appliance operation is off topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just googled why a stove would have a lock on it.  Seems to be for a child safety feature that you need a child to open.   Do not know how we all survived without this.  We only needed to touch a hot stove once.

Comment: I think it is also meant to be helpful to avoid accidental usage. The stovetop is the style that is essentially a flat surface, so I can easily imagine people setting things on it (boxes, produce, whatever) as a normal countertop, and then then bumping a button to turn on the stovetop… It’s electric, silent, and it could cause a fire.

Comment: It also says "Induction", so unless those things they put on the stove before accidentally turning it on are metal, there won't be a problem. You can put your bare hand on an induction burner turned all the way up and so long as you don't have metal rings on, you won't feel the slightest bit of heat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> (1) Lock: Touch [lock] key more than 4 seconds, [lock] icon shows in LED, it is
> locked, there is no function to touch any other keys.
>
> (2) Unlock: Touch [lock] key more than 4 seconds again, [lock] icon doesn't show, then it is unlocked. Maybe touch more than 4 seconds to turn off all functions

[Empava Manual](https://www.overstock.com/downloads/pdf/1350249599_05096a8b-a292-361d-ac8c-43bbe81b160a.pdf)